# DUMPBIN /SECTION syntax

Tags: dumpbin

I have an OBJ with 2c1 sections.  How can I dump the header of only section 101?

`dumpbin /HEADERS /SECTION:101 file.obj` gives me the whole list.  The same thing as `dumpbin /HEADERS file.obj` with the added line:

```
LINK : warning LNK4039: section '101' specified with /SECTION option does not exist
```

But it does:

```
SECTION HEADER #101
  .rdata name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
      10 size of raw data
   11A9C file pointer to raw data (00011A9C to 00011AAB)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40301040 flags
         Initialized Data
         COMDAT; sym= EP_Commands
         4 byte align
         Read Only
```

The [/SECTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6c8asf.aspx) documentation doesn't help.  [Geoff](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/link/dump/options/section.htm?ts=0,127) say's the section name is case sensitive.  I have tried decimal numbers.  I have tried hex numbers.  I have tried `#101`.  I have tried `sect101`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using section number instead of section name. Here is the command-line to get the details of only the above section you have mentioned in your question:

```
dumpbin /HEADERS /SECTION:.rdata file.obj
```